# Aborted Ubuntu installation

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, wubi, ubuntu-core

I  have aborted an Ubuntu installation.
Now the label and icon  of one of my disk drive is changed to

## Install Ubuntu (C:)

I tried to rename it manually but i failed.
Can it be fixed ?[image: x]

Comment: Do not use wubi for installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label name and icon are defined in file **autorun.inf**.

e.g. **autorun.inf** from **ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso** contains the following lines:

```
[autorun]
open=wubi.exe
icon=wubi.exe,0
label=Install Ubuntu

[Content]
MusicFiles=false
PictureFiles=false
VideoFiles=false
```

If you change or delete this file on Windows drive **C:**, you will get your old label name and icon of your disk.

Answer (score 0):

Hence, autorun.inf contains the executable to run. It is showing over the C: drive.

Simple remove it using the rm command or if not, try -f for force.